# Is it possible to allow the person submitting a webform with CiviCRM to decide whether an activity is created or now?

Tags: webform-civicrm

Is it possible to expose a field on the webform to the person submitting the form to allow them to decide if the activity is created?

There are some situations where we would want the person submitting the form to decide if they would like to create a follow up activity,

Thanks

Comment: I've never tried to expose a field to specify optional actons. If there is no browser based way to do it then it seems like it should be fairly easy to hook on form submission to chech a submitted value and then call the API to create an activity.

Answer (score 4):

The following steps should do it (requires version 4.10+ of the webform-civicrm integration module):

1. Make the "Activity Type" field "User Select"
2. Customize that field to remove all options except for "None" and the activity type you want.
3. Optionally rename the field on the webform "Create Activity"
4. Optionally rename the option labels to "Yes" and "No"

Comment: Coleman - since the OP talked about a 'follow up' activity - and since civi does have the concept of Parent ID for an Activity to create a link, is this possible in civicrm currently? also any chance you could comment on http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16002/should-the-link-between-an-activity-and-any-follow-up-activity-be-visible-throug

Comment: meant "possible in webform-civicrm" but can't now edit comment

Comment: Sorry webform-civicrm doesn't currently do follow-up-activity linking.