# Should the link between an Activity and any Follow Up activity be visible through the UI

Tags: activities

I checked that when creating a Follow Up activity, it adds a value to  civicrm_activity.parent_id so that at least the database knows there is a connection between these, but afaik there is nothing visible on the Activities tab of the contact, nor within either of those Activities if you click 'View'.

While researching this I spotted Find Activities does have radio buttons for is / has a follow up Activity.

Would it make sense for the child and parent Activities to show there is a connection both on the Activity itself and on the Activity Tab

(info based on a 4.6.x version)

EDIT: Spotted this [ticket](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-3777) (for civi 2.2.x - wow) that says:

```
5. Provide link back to parent activity when viewing a follow-up activity
Modify ActivityView to check if parent_id is NOT NULL
If NOT NULL, assign $parentURL to template - this should be a link to view the "parent" activity. (ActivityView.tpl already has logic to display this link if it's got a value).
"Prompted by..."
```

But I am having no luck seeing this in action on d46 or master. If this did exist and has been lost or removed can anyone confirm if this was intentional? Or is this a Regression?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there never was a visible link.  I certainly don't remember seeing one, and I've always treated the follow-up feature as simply a convenience for creating multiple activities rather than establishing some kind of relationship.

If there were to be a visible link, I (as a user) would expect the ability to break links and create new links between existing activities.